# Facebook's FB.ui feed method is not working on some Android phones

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, fb.ui

**Description:**

I have implemented facebook Fb.ui feed method to share some data including picture on facebook and to get post id in reply.
My code except init method etc is:

**Code:**

```
            <script>
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({appId: 'myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
                    };
                    (function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true; e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                    }());
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#share_button').click(function(e){
                            var isMobile = false; //initiate as false                               
                            // device detection                                     
                            (function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))isMobile = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);                                     
                            var displayy = 'popup';
                            if(isMobile)
                                displayy = 'touch';
                            e.preventDefault();
                            FB.ui(
                                {
                                  method: 'feed',
                                  name: 'mytitle',
                                  link: 'mylink',
                                  display: displayy,
                                  picture: 'imageurl',
                                  description: 'share description'                                  },
                                function(response) {
                                  if (response) {
                                    console.log(response);
                                    alert('Post was successfull published.');
                                  } else {
                                    alert('Post was not published. Error occured');
                                  }
                                }
                            );
                        });
                    });
            </script>
```

**Problem:**

Now problem is this code is working correctly on all browsers (Tested on safari, Chrome, Explorer, Firefox), iOS and some Androids, but when I runs it on some Androids (I tested 2-3, it can be many) like samsung s6 edge series or gt-s7262 etc, It does not redirects after sharing post.

One more thing on Android 6.0 and higher when I scan my qrcode to open URL it shows me different options to open that URL in like in browser, in native app etc. When I use browser option it works as well and when I choose any other option it does not work.

**Possible Solution:**

Maybe I am missing something in checking device type or maybe I am missing some display type, but I don't know what's wrong here.

**What I already tried:**

I already tried feed dialogue sharing html code with redirect_ui parameter and also tried many solution found on Google and Stack Overflow about `fb.ui` method like changing display type to iframe etc. but all these could not solve my issue.

**I also want:**

I also want to test this for all mobile devices and tablets, How could I do that as well?